# Generics in c#: "two levels of indirection"

Tags: c#, generics

There is a piece of code that I would implement like this in java:

```
public void doIt( T extends MyEventArgs<? extends MyBaseClass> obj ) {
   ...
}
```

How would I do that in c#? I first thought this would be it:

```
public void oIt( T obj ) where T : MyEventArgs<P> where P : MyBaseClass {
    ...
}
```

But apparantly my syntax is wrong.

any ideas?

PS: don't ask me why I'm doing this. Please :)

Comment: why are you doing this? --- sorry couldn't resist ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just missing the generic type arguments:

```
public void oIt<T,P>( T obj )
     where T : MyEventArgs<P>
     where P : MyBaseClass
{
     ...
}
```

(the names `oIt`, `T`, `P` and `obj` could probably be clearer, but I'll assume that is anonymisation)

Comment: By the way, the compiler won't be able to infer the type parameters for you if you do this. You should manually specify both T and P when you call the method.